# Short Story about unexpected first contact

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, first-contact

I'm trying to help my dad identify a short story he read when he was young.  So it must have been written in early 70s or before.

Synopsis as he remembers it:

The far space scout lands his ship on another planet (uninhabited) and plans to take a little break. He notices another ship landing not far from him, which delights him as he has been quite tired of loneliness and now there will be someone to talk to. They meet outside their ships (tired of the confined space), chat away about life and what it's like being deep space scouts etc... At some point, one of them notices the that the other's suit is different and asks what it is.  He asks if scouts are getting new uniforms. The second one replies that it is just a standard suit and that he is unfamiliar with the first astronaut's suit either. And then it dawns on them that they are from different worlds.

Comment: It's the first contact between their two different worlds, and yet they speak the same language? How is that?

Comment: @user14111 I think I remember the story and they were from alternate Earths not different planets in our universe.

Comment: I recall an old story about unexpected first contact when an Earth ship encounters an alien ship inside a nebula, then both crews must figure out a way to return home without the other ship being able to follow. (The contact is friendly, but both crews are cautious.)

Comment: @StanleyWebb Your story is "First Contact" by  Murray Leinster.